# Why this regex is causing infinity loop?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function listPlayers(subject){
    var players=[];

    var myregexp = /(\S*)(?:,\s|$)/g;
    var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
    while (match != null) {
         players.push(match[1]);
         match = myregexp.exec(subject);
    }
    return players;
}
```

The string I'm trying to match is like this `�r Henderson�r�f, Pedrin�r�f, �c~�lArthur�r�f, John�r�f`

The output I expect is an array like this `['Henderson�r�f', 'Pedrin�r�f', '�c~�lArthur�r�f', 'John�r�f']`

What I don't understand is on regex buddy everything seems ok.
[image]

Comment: The problem is `*` together with the lookahead. At the end, the expression matches without consuming any characters (it does not have to because of the `*`, but it matches the last position, because of the lookeahead), so `.exec` is stuck.

Comment: @FelixKling: Correct in essence, but there's no lookahead in the OP's regex.  It's the `$` anchor that's doing him in, along with JavaScript's broken-by-design handling of zero-width matches and the `exec()` method. ([ref](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/exec-bugs))

Comment: @Alan: Oh right... just saw the `(?...` and ignored the next character... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for interest, a perhaps simpler way using a zero-width positive lookahead assertion:

```
function listPlayers( subject ) {
    return subject.match( /\S+(?=,\s|$)/g );
}
```

Comment: +1.  Changing `\S*` to `\S+` is what fixes the immediate problem, but this approach returns exactly what you want: an array of all the names with the commas and whitespace already stripped off.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing my mistake, I choose this answer because I like this solution. I was trying to archive this result with `non-capturing groups`, but I didn't knew that the `lookahead` does not return the `lookahead` itself, which is what I want.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the regexp to:

```
var myregexp = /(\S+)(?:,\s|$)/g;
```

I think the loop may be because it repeatedly matches an empty string at the end.

Since I don't think you're interested in getting zero-length names, this is probably a better regexp in general.